# Python combine lists from a function output

Tags: python, list

The output of these functions are 3 separate lists of all the IP's within the range from whois data for the addresses in list d. I want to be able to combine them into one long list of addresses to use in another function.

These are 3 random addresses I have found that don't lie within a giant /16 that takes ages to run

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois
import ipaddress

d = ['185.62.33.1', '185.62.50.1', '185.62.70.1']

def ipwho(d):

    ipaddrlist = d
    ipaddrlist = list(set(ipaddrlist))
    x = []
    for dnsdip in ipaddrlist:
        try:
            obj = IPWhois(str(dnsdip).strip('\n'))
            results = obj.lookup_rdap(asn_methods=['whois'])
            x.append(results['network']['cidr'])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    for address in x:
        cidr_to_iplist(address)

def cidr_to_iplist(address):
    y = []
    cidrx = address
    set1 = ipaddress.ip_network(cidrx)
    ip_list=[str(ip) for ip in set1]
    for ipv4 in ip_list:
        y.append(ipv4)
    print(y)

ipwho(d)
```

Comment: You need to change your functions to use `return` to get values back from them.

Answer (score 1):

Basically @quamrana already answered your question, but I wanted to point out a couple of things.

1. `ipaddrlist = d` <-- using this is wastefull. You already have the variable passed as an argument to the method, so why assign it to another one?
2. Using variables named like `x` and `y` is not advised if they are meaningfull variables. Always name your variables to something that makes it easy to understand what they are/do/contain.
3. In the `ipwho()` method you loop through the variables twice. Slight reordering of the logic saves you a loop.
4. Converting the list to a set to remove duplicates is smart thinking, but no need to convert it back to a list for the logic you're using.

As for having the methods return something, the [return](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_return.asp) statement followed by fe. a variable will do what you want.

If you use `list.extend(list)` you can add a list to a list. See [w3school docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_extend.asp).

```py
from ipwhois import IPWhois
import ipaddress
from pprint import pprint


d = ["185.62.33.1", "185.62.50.1", "185.62.70.1"]


def ipwho(ipaddrlist):
    ipaddrlist = set(ipaddrlist)
    result = []
    for dnsdip in ipaddrlist:
        try:
            obj = IPWhois(str(dnsdip).strip("\n"))
            lookup = obj.lookup_rdap(asn_methods=["whois"])
            result.extend(cidr_to_iplist(lookup["network"]["cidr"]))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return result


def cidr_to_iplist(address):
    result = []
    ip_list = [str(ip) for ip in ipaddress.ip_network(address)]
    for ipv4 in ip_list:
        result.append(ipv4)
    return result


pprint(ipwho(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little refactor of your program which will return the ipv4 objects in a list:

```py
from ipwhois import IPWhois
import ipaddress

def ipwho(d):
    return [
        ipaddress.ip_network(x)
        for x in [
            IPWhois(x).lookup_rdap(asn_methods=['whois'])['network']['cidr']
            for x in set(d)
        ] if x ]

who = ipwho(['185.62.33.1', '185.62.50.1', '185.62.70.1'])
print(who)
```